Pygame Offset Grid by Fraction or Pixels
I am working on a Chess block by following a YT video, but I want my board more centered. I did that, however, now my event.get() event.pos isn't working quite right. About 15 pixels from the bottom of the square actually is considered the square below (The board is offset at the top by 15 pixels). While I could just move the board up, I would like to keep the board where it is. Is there a way to offset the pygame coordinates? Is there a way to get a decimal to work with my code in the y-axis? If the code below is too long, I have attached the link to my github Chess Folder on GitHub
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

width = 1500
height = 1000
screen = pg.display.set_mode([width, height])
pg.display.set_caption("Play Chess")
font = pg.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
big_font = pg.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 50)
timer = pg.time.Clock()
fps = 60
blocks = 8 ** 2
turn_select = 0
selection = 100
valid_moves = []

def Draw_Board():
    for i in range(blocks // 2):
        column = i % 4
        row = i // 4

        if row % 2 == 0:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, 'cadetblue', [900 - (column * 200), (row * 100) + 15, 100, 100])
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, 'cadetblue', [1000 - (column * 200), (row * 100) + 15, 100, 100])

        if (row + 1) % 2 == 0:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, 'silver', [900 - (column * 200), (row * 100) + 15, 100, 100])
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, 'silver', [1000 - (column * 200), (row * 100) + 15, 100, 100])


running = True
while running:
    timer.tick(fps)
    screen.fill("darkgreen")

    Draw_Board()
    if turn_select < 2:
        if selection < 2:
                pg.draw.rect(
                    screen, 'red', 
                    [white_loc[i][0] * 100 + 300, 
                        white_loc[i][1] * 100 + 16, 99, 99], 1)
    
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            x_coor = event.pos[0] // 100 - 3
            y_coor = event.pos[1] // 100 
            #I want to put -0.15 here but it won't work
            
            clk_coor = (x_coor, y_coor)

            #For White
            if turn_select < 2:
                if clk_coor in white_loc:
                    selection = white_loc.index(clk_coor)
                    if turn_select == 0:
                        turn_select = 1
                if clk_coor in valid_moves and selection != 100:
                    white_loc[selection] = clk_coor
                    if clk_coor in black_loc:
                        black_piece = black_loc.index(clk_coor)
                        captured_white.append(black_pieces[black_piece])
                        black_pieces.pop(black_piece)
                        black_loc.pop(black_piece)
                    
                    black_ops = check_ops(black_pieces, black_loc, 'black')
                    white_ops = check_ops(white_pieces, white_loc, 'white')
                    turn_select = 2
                    selection = 100
                    valid_moves = []

    pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()




You add fifteen to the y rect position in Draw_Board(), if you want to figure out the board coordinate, you need to subtract fifteen from event.pos[1] before dividing by 100. You should probably create an explicit function to determine the board square from the mouse position. See this answer.
